# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user' ERROR DJANGO

Tags: python, django

it's this error that I don't understand , and i don't understand why i can't use user attribute off request and POST attribute

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.connect,name='connect'),
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from .form import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def connect(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == True:
        test=True
    form = connect(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user == None:
            return render(request,'etudiant/home.html',locals())
        else:
            parent = Parent.objects.get(personne=user)
            admin = Administrateur.objects.get(personne=user)
            if parent != None:
                par=True
            if admin != None:
                ad=True

    return render(request, 'etudiant/home.html', locals())
```

[image: this is my error]

Comment: What is `connect(request.POST or None)` supposed to mean? `connect` is the view that is being executed. Obviously you would receive an error (If not the one you receive then one because of the infinite recursion).

Comment: Did you define a *form* named `connect`? Since you also have a view with that name, and you thus here make a recursive call instead.

Comment: Its a form class defined in form.py

Comment: @AnasRaghib: rename the form (or the view) such that `connect(request.POST or None)` does not point to the view, but to the form.

Comment: Normally it is also not a good idea to do wildcard imports.

Comment: Ok  i will try your solution and i ll see the results thank you !

Comment: it work Thanks To You guys !!